# How to debug ns-3 in python

Tags: python, debugging

when I run a ns-3 simulation written in Python and something fails, I only see this message:

```
Command ['/usr/bin/python', 'path/to/file.py'] terminated with signal SIGSEGV. Run it under a debugger to get more information (./waf --run <program> --command-template="gdb --args %s <args>").
```

But I can not see the actual error message.

I run the simulation with:

```
sudo ./waf --pyrun path/to/file.py
```

Could somebody tell me how to run the simulation to see the error message?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message suggests?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. The result is the same.